# Low convergence of a perturbation solution to a non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I have the following first-order non-linear ODE:

$$
\frac{1}{12}y' + \frac{1}{40} \epsilon \left( y' \right)^3 = -1  \tag{1}\label{1}
$$

where $y=y(x), \enspace x\in \left[0,1\right], \enspace \epsilon \ll 1$ is the perturbation parameter, and Eq. \eqref{1} is subject to,

$$
y(1) = 0. \tag{2}\label{2} 
$$

I sought a perturbation solution in powers of $\epsilon$ expanding $y$ as follows,

$$
y = y_0 + y_1 \epsilon + y_2 \epsilon^2 + \cdots. \tag{3}\label{3} 
$$

Substituting \eqref{3} in \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} produces the following problems:

$ O(1): $
$$
\frac{1}{12}y_0'  = -1 \\ y_0(1) = 0
$$

$ O(\epsilon): $
$$
\frac{1}{12}y_1' + \frac{1}{40} \left( y_0' \right)^3 = 0 \\ y_1(1) = 0
$$

$ O(\epsilon^2): $
$$
\frac{1}{12}y_2' + \frac{3}{40} \left( y_0' \right)^2 y_1' = 0 \\ y_2(1) = 0
$$

The corresponding solutions are:

$$
y_0 = 12(1-x), \tag{4}\label{4} 
$$

$$
y_1 = -\frac{2592}{5}(1-x), \tag{5}\label{5} 
$$

$$
y_2 = \frac{1679616}{25}(1-x). \tag{6}\label{6} 
$$

Then, inserting Eqs. \eqref{4}-\eqref{6} in \eqref{3} yields the perturbation solution up to $ O(\epsilon^2) $. Finally, the exact solution of \eqref{1} is presented to measure the accuracy of \eqref{3}, namely

$$
y = \frac{ \sqrt[3]{100} \epsilon - \sqrt[3]{10 \alpha^2} }{ 3 \epsilon \sqrt[3]{\alpha} } (1-x), \tag{7}\label{7} 
$$

where $ \alpha = \sqrt{ 2 \epsilon^3 \left( 1458 \epsilon + 5 \right)  } - 54 \epsilon^2 $.

Now, the exact solution \eqref{7} is plotted with its corresponding numerical solution (via MATLAB `ode15i` function). Figure 1 shows a perfect agreement between the exact and the numerical solution.

[Figure 1. Exact and numerical solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2GWO.png)

Here comes my problem (after all this wordiness). Figure 2 shows that the perturbation solution \eqref{3} only converges to the exact solution \eqref{7} for *really small values* of $\epsilon$, namely, $\epsilon \sim O(10^{-3})$. The title in each subplot shows the $\epsilon$ value and the relative error of the perturbation solution to the exact solution. This means that the contributions of $O(\epsilon)$ and higher-order terms are not important, and all the physics of the problem is driven by the leading-order solution $y_0$ \eqref{4}.

[Figure 2. Perturbation and exact solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBGcC.png)

**Questions:**

1. Did I achieve a correct perturbation solution?
2. Is this non-linear equation not suitable for a regular expansion approach?
3. Why does the perturbation parameter need to be so *small*?

A final comment. I proposed $ y = y_0 + y_1 \epsilon^\beta + \cdots,$ and I got $ \beta = 1$.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote (1) correctly? It is not really an ODE as written.

Comment: Since you have the exact solution, have you tried expanding it in $\epsilon$?

Comment: @copper.hat: It's a non-linear first-order ODE written _implicit_, $f(y',x)=0$. We can solve for $y'$ and obtain the explicit representation, $y' = g(x)$. But, since it's a third-grade polynomial equation in $y'$, the right-hand side of that rearranging deems to be _ugly_.

Comment: @lcv: Good point. I'll do it, but the road is dreadful.

Comment: The coefficients of the perturbation series grow very fast. $ϵ$ must at least be within the radius of convergence. The exact expression has a singularity at $-5/1458$, which is a bound on the radius of convergence.

Comment: There are at most 3 solutions for $y'$ so presumably $y'$ is constant and the solution is just $y(x) = (x-1) y'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the solution as

$$
y(x) = \gamma(\epsilon) (1-x)  \ \ \ \quad \mathrm(0)
$$

we see that $\gamma$ must satisfy

$$
\gamma^3\frac{\epsilon}{40}+\frac{\gamma}{12} -1=0.  \ \ \ \quad \mathrm(1)
$$

This is a cubic equation so it always has one real solution which is

$$
g(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{10^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{2}
   \sqrt{1458 \epsilon ^4+5 \epsilon ^3}-54 \epsilon
   ^2}}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{10} \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{2}
   \sqrt{1458 \epsilon ^4+5 \epsilon ^3}-54 \epsilon
   ^2}}{\epsilon }\right).
$$

Now, the polynomial in (1) changes order when $\epsilon=0$ so you don't even have guarantee that the solution is continuous in $\epsilon$ at zero. Indeed $g(\epsilon)$ is complex for $\epsilon<0$. Computing the derivatives as $\epsilon \to 0^+$ one obtains

$$
g(\epsilon) = 12-\frac{2592 \epsilon }{5}+\frac{1679616 \epsilon
   ^2}{25}+O\left(\epsilon ^{3}\right),  \ \ \ \quad \mathrm(3)
$$

so your calculation is correct. However  the coefficients $a_n$ of this expansion defined as

$$
g(\epsilon) = \sum_{n=0} a_n \epsilon^n   \ \ \ \quad \mathrm(4)
$$

grow exponentially $a_n \sim b a^n$ (with $a\approx 186.9$, $b\approx3.14$) which means that the series (4) diverges for $\epsilon a >1$.  I think this explains what you are observing. You could make it even more evident by plotting the exact form of $g(\epsilon)$ together with one of its Taylor approximants.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. Just a final question. In Eqs. (0) and (1), is $\gamma$ the same as your later $g(\epsilon)$?

Comment: Yes it's (essentially) the same. $g$ is one solution of the polynomial whose variable I denoted with $\gamma$. $\gamma_1$ would probably have been a better notation but I was lazy about typing.